# Migrating Django model field from TextField to ArrayField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-migration

I'm migrating an existing PostgreSQL database to Django and a lot of the fields are TextFields but include lists encoded as JSON (which is what the previously used ORM used). So naturally when `inspectdb` was used on the database the created models use `TextField`. I'd like to actually turn these into Django's `ArrayField`, a PostgreSQL-specific field.

The generated migration doesn't seem to handle this well and crashes with:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: missing dimension value
```

Also, would the text actually be decoded as a list and stored that way or would it simply take the JSON-encoded string and store it as a single value list?

Comment: If the field contains JSON, wouldn't maybe `JSONField` be more appropriate?

Comment: Did you check this issue at GitHub: https://github.com/ecometrica/django-dbarray/issues/2 ?

Comment: @cezar I guess so but it requires PostgreSQL 9.4 and I have only 9.2 available. I did check out that issue and already have `null=True` in all the `ArrayField`s.